# Why does tf.reduce_mean() return NaN values? I'm trying to calculate the Mean Squared error, but I keep getting NaN values

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the code I'm using:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession() 
self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.state_space]) 
self.Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.action_space]) 
layer1 = tf.layers.dense(self.X, 128, activation = tf.nn.leaky_relu) 
layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 64, activation = tf.nn.leaky_relu) 
layer3 = tf.layers.dense(layer2, 32, activation = tf.nn.leaky_relu)
self.outputs = tf.layers.dense(layer3, self.action_space, activation='softmax') 
self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.Y - self.outputs))
#self.loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.Y - self.outputs)) + 1.0e-12)
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-6).minimize(self.loss)   
self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

I tried a few basic changes such as adding a small constant, using tf.log(), etc, but nothing has worked till now.

Thank you, in advance, to anyone who can help!

Comment: You probably have some NaNs in your data. Check your data.

Comment: I preprocessed my dataset and then re-checked for NaN values. I don't have NaN values there.

Comment: If you have an extra 0 dim in your tensor reduce mean can nan out and adding a constant will not help. E.g. `a = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.constant([[],[]])))` will give `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=nan>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the loss function to work by changing the tensorflow version.

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
%tensorflow_version 1.x

ops.reset_default_graph()
```

Then, while setting up my trader (which is defined as a class in my code), I added the following snippet:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

I'm glad this works now, but I still don't understand why this couldn't be solved using my original code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Until I added these snippets, I had been working with Tensorflow 2.4.1.
If anyone knows the answer, kindly comment/answer below. Cheers!